# Sphinx sentence like query

Tags: search, sphinx

my task is to find a similar sentence in database collection.

Could you advise me which query type to use?

Sample:
**Search:** *Welcome to the first sample code.*

And let say the following sentences are fine for my query:

**Dbase:**

...

Welcome in first movie ...

This is first sample code ...

Welcome!
...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If I got it correctly, each sentence in the DB, which includes one or more words from the search query, is fine.

In this case, you have to use the `SPH_MATCH_ANY` mode or `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2` with `|` (OR) operator.

[Matching modes...](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#matching-modes)

[Extended query syntax...](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#extended-syntax)

If you want to exclude such words as "to", "the" and other short words, you have several options:

1) If you are sure that each word which is less than 4 letters should be excluded, add the following line to your `sphinx.conf` file:

```
min_word_len = 4
```

[Read more...](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#conf-min-word-len)

2) if you want to exclude specific words, use the stopwords file(s).

Add the following lines to `sphinx.conf`:

```
#path to txt file with words to be excluded (space separated)
stopwords = /usr/local/sphinx/configuration/stopwords.txt
```

[Read more...](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#conf-stopwords)

And the last thing you should know is that I just provided very basic things which are clearly explained in the documentation and my examples are also taken from there.